# Accidentally copied files over /bin/bash in OS X

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, finder

I mistakenly copied two files over `/bin/bash`. This now made my terminal [non-responsive](http://nicholasworkshop.com/2013/03/30/save-terminal-from-process-completed-in-mac-osx/).  I've followed [this](http://lifehacker.com/5711409/how-to-search-for-hidden-packaged-and-system-files-in-os-x) tutorial but it didn't help.

For reference, the files are `runcocoa.sh` and `runc.sh` to be specific, from this [tutorial](https://github.com/michaeltyson/Commandline-Cocoa)). I also copied them to `/usr/local/bin`, but then I deleted them…

How can I restore the functionality of my system?

Comment: Have you tried another terminal emulator, like iterm or cathode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went to *Terminal » Preferences » Startup* and changed *Shells open with* from *Default login shell* to *Command*, and used another shell (e.g. `/bin/csh` rather than my original `/bin/bash`).

This made my terminal functional again – and using [this](http://nicholasworkshop.com/2013/03/30/save-terminal-from-process-completed-in-mac-osx/) tutorial, I installed a newer version of Bash to replace the `/bin/bash` I originally overwrote.

I cut and pasted these lines:

```
curl -LO ftp://ftp.cwru.edu/pub/bash/bash-4.2.tar.gz
tar zxvf bash-4.2.tar.gz
cd bash-4.2
./configure && make && sudo make install
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash {user_name}
sudo bash -c "echo /usr/local/bin/bash >> /private/etc/shells"
cd /bin
sudo mv bash bash-old
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/bash bash
```

And done!

Comment: This only fixes your symptoms, not the actual problem. Changing the system-default Bash 3.x to 4.2 might have you run into other issues as you go … You should rather save your data and reinstall OS X, or restore from a Time Machine backup.

Comment: @slhck ugh.. that's hardly comforting.. but what i didn't understand is how can simply copying a file into a certain location cause so much damage to my terminal? isn't that action undoable (assuming i can locate those files)? reinstalling osx seems like an overkill

Comment: You did not just copy, you overwrote `/bin/bash` and so deleted `bash` from your system. The terminal works through `bash` so if there is no `bash` you get no terminal. You should be able to reinstall the `bash` you deleted by replacing `bash-4.2.tar.gz` in the FTP URL in your answer with the appropriate `bash` version for your system or copy `/bin/bash` from your backup. I don't OSX but this should work. @slhck am I wrong?

Comment: I upgraded my `/bin/bash` to 4.2 a while ago (Mt. Lion) and haven't had any issues. I kept a backup of the original (of course) in case anything came up, but 4.2 seems backwards-compatible enough that any system scripts relying on it haven't failed, to my knowledge.

Comment: @terdon If the OP only overwrote that, of course it can be put back from a backup easily. It wasn't clear what exactly they did in the first place, so I took the safe route :)

Comment: @slhck oh no! the moderator just got moderated!! lol kidding thanks guys for all the help.. i learned a lot! my first post at super user was a pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, you can use Terminal by changing the command that shells open with to something like /bin/sh:

[image]

The /bin/sh and /bin/bash binaries are almost identical, so you can just copy /bin/sh over /bin/bash.

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines -W 80 <(strings /bin/bash) <(strings /bin/sh)
                                      > /bin/bash
${FCEDIT:-${EDITOR:-ed}}              | ${FCEDIT:-ed}
@(#)PROGRAM:bash  PROJECT:bash-86.1   | @(#)PROGRAM:sh  PROJECT:bash-86.1
```

Most of the differences between /bin/sh and /bin/bash depend on the name the shell was invoked with. On other platforms /bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/bash. See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89311/are-bash-bourne-and-korn-shells-compiled-into-one-binary-in-osx).

The recovery partition also includes a bash binary. It's smaller because it doesn't support i386, but it was identical with the binary created by `lipo -thin x86_64 /bin/bash -output /tmp/bash` on my installation.

```
$ diskutil mount 'Recovery HD'
$ hdiutil mount /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.dmg
$ stat -f %z /bin/bash /Volumes/OS\ X\ 10.8.2\ Base\ System/bin/bash
1333920
699040
$ file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/bin/bash (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
/bin/bash (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
$ file /Volumes/OS\ X\ 10.8.2\ Base\ System/bin/bash
/Volumes/OS X 10.8.2 Base System/bin/bash: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
$ lipo -thin x86_64 /bin/bash -output /tmp/bash
$ stat -f %z /tmp/bash
699040
$ diff /tmp/bash /Volumes/OS\ X\ 10.8.2\ Base\ System/bin/bash
$
```